# Will the post owner lose points if an answer was edited several times?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, answers

Today I made a tiny edit to an answer. Then someone added a comment mentioning me that making edits to an answer before it's getting accepted will cause a loss of points for the post owner.

I asked him for any proof of his statement then he said that he had some experience with that kind of thing for his own posts. I would have neglected that but his account holds more than 6.5K rep with over 350 answers and member for 5 years, which means he knows something about the site.

The person did not clearly state what are *points*. I believe it's reputation. So is that true?

Comment: I've never heard of that being a thing and I am having a difficult time believing it is true. Most of the time someone mentions *points* around here they are indeed referring to reputation.

Comment: You do make a lot of very small edits.  No longer vetted by the review queue, it is now done by re-activating the Q+A.  This can cause friction, somebody might see them too often and getting tired of it, especially in a small tag.  There is no decent way to talk you out of doing that, other than by spinning a good-sounding tale :)

Comment: @HansPassant I see... I know that _Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged_ but sometimes I find those tiny spelling mistakes and formatting problems are disappointing. :(

Comment: What may be disappointing is if an active user in a very small tag sees the same mediocre questions multiple times because of these tiny edits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since both of you are over 2K reputation, you won't lose reputation for edits. The only time *that* applies anyway is if a suggested edit is rejected or reversed, which doesn't sound like it'd apply.

Otherwise, this is simply untrue.  You're not going to lose reputation for editing a post multiple times.

They *might* have been referring to a time when X number of edits would turn the post into Community Wiki which would prevent anyone from getting reputation, but that's been *long* since removed as a thing that happens.

Comment: "Since both of you are over 2K reputation, you won't [gain] reputation for edits".

Comment: _. The only time that applies anyway is if a suggested edit is rejected or reversed, which doesn't sound like it'd apply._ Is there something like this? Link please

Answer (score 1):

I've never had that happen, either when I edit an answer or when someone else edits their answer to my question, nor have I seen that in the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), so I'd say no, not true.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the author of the post nor the editor will lose points because a post was edited, whether before or after acceptance by the OP. As other users have suggested, this could be a misunderstanding of some sort, and the other user was thinking of an entirely different scenario. Otherwise, it’s just not true.